# Getting "Maximum execution time" error intermittently

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing this problem, firstly I would like to say that I am very new to PHP and MySQL.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in 
.........................\cdn\wished.php on line 3
```

I don't know what is wrong in line 3, its giving error only sometimes. Here's my code:

```
<?php
//wished.php
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ownerid='$user->id'");
$wished = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($CheckQuery))
{
//  echo $row['fname']."<br/>";
    $wished++;
}
echo $wished;
?>
```

It was perfect when I run this in localhost with **XAMPP**. As soon as I hosted my app on my domain and used their database, it start getting error.

thanks every one :)

Comment: is it fast when you directly run the query on mysql?

Comment: Is `users` a large table?

Comment: or your database is not responding....

Comment: user is not really large

Comment: How many rows does `users` contain, and how many rows does the `SELECT` statement return? Are you running this code on a local machine with your database on the local machine, or are you running it remotely with a database on a different machine? Please add more details.

Comment: If all you do is is counting then you should do `SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE ownerid='$user->id'` instead and echo that.

Comment: @JakubKania thanks i will try to use count(*) function :)

Comment: Maybe the mySQL server goes away, or there is some other timeout problem when connecting to the mySQL server? Where is it running?

Comment: make sure you have index on ownerid field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the SQL query is taking too long, and your production PHP configuration has the PHP script time limit set too low.

At the beginning of the script you can add more time to the PHP time limit:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

`set_time_limit(60);`

for example to add 30 more seconds (or use 0 to let the PHP script continue running).

If your production database is different than your development DB (and I'm assuming production has way more data) then it might be a really expensive call to get everything from the user table.

Comment: set_time_limit(0);  will make it take as long as it want?

Comment: @deerox Yes, that's correct. No time limit will be imposed on the script (but it's not always the best solution). You might want to debug the DB call first because there might be some issue with it taking so long. If you happen to write some sort of infinite loop, the PHP script won't stop running since there will be no time limit on the script execution.

Comment: i have few loop in the app as well thanks so much for making it clear to me :)

Comment: Note that the webserver will have a time limit, even if PHP's time limit is set to 0; set_time_limit(0) is only unlimited if you're running your PHP script from the command line